# Test a method with no params using Spock (groovy) data table

Tags: java, groovy, spock

Assuming the method I am trying to test is:

```
private void deleteImages() {
  //iterate files in path
  //if file == image then delete
}
```

Now to test this using groovy with spock framework, I am making 2 files, and calling the method:

```
def "delete images"() {
given:
    //create new folder and get path to "path"
    File imageFile = new File(path, "image.jpg")
    imageFile.createNewFile()
    File textFile= new File(path, "text.txt")
    textFile.createNewFile()
}
when:
   myclass.deleteImages()

then:
   !imageFile.exists()
   textFile.exists()
```

This is working as expected.

However, I want to add more files to this test (eg: more image file extensions, video file extensions etc) and therefore using a data table would be easier to read.

How can I convert this to a data table? Note that my test method does not take any parameters (the directory path is mocked via another service, which I have not added here for simplicity).

All the data table examples I saw were based on varying the input to a single method, but in my case, the setup is what is different, while the method takes no inputs.

Ideally, after the setup, I would like to see a table like this:

```
   where:
    imageFileJPG.exists()   | false
    imageFileTIF.exists()   | false
    imageFilePNG.exists()   | false
    videoFileMP4.exists()   | true
    videoFileMOV.exists()   | true
    videoFileMKV.exists()   | true
```

Comment: Tables are useful to run multiple permutations of the same test.  I think you just want more files for one test?  Please add what you have tried so it might become more clear. For the path problem you will be way better off having a config, that your service uses and your tests can either provide (e.g. use /var/tmp or the tests so no dev-files get removed) or at least can reuse.

Comment: @cfrick I dont have a path problem (I will make it clearer in the question), just want to know if data tables is a suitable approach for adding more files to this test eg: multiple image files with different extensions etc. I could not find anything online about this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a data table, you should put DATA in there instead of method calls.

So, the test could look like this:

```
@Unroll
def 'some test for #fileName and #result'() {
  expect:
  File f = new File( fileName )
  myclass.deleteImages()
  f.exists() == result

  where:
      fileName        | result
    'imageFile.JPG'   | false
    'imageFile.TIF'   | false
    'videoFile.MKV'   | true
    .....
}
```